# The wan of EternalBlue and DoublePulsar

Tags: linux, exploit

I have an ideea how the thing works in a LAN sceneryo but on WAN...
So my question is simple, is there any way to use EternalBlue and DoublePulsar to hack outside the LAN ?

Comment: Voting to close because question is not about programming

Comment: Voting to keep open because programmers shouldn't have a myopic view as to what is about "programming" and this affects a wide swath of users and platforms. --DevOps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EternalBlue uses SMBv1 as primary protocol to copy itself onto other devices.
If someone has SMB port open to the WAN then yes you can use EternalBlue for it.

---

Side note: if someone has SMB open to WAN then they deserve to get hacked, that port is not meant to be open to WAN.

Answer (score 0):

If I opened a NGROK tcp tunnel on port 445 Which is smb port then we can exploit the port through the ngrok url along with the port. We can't use this trick in real pentesting  because we need to set the ngrok tunnel first to exploit. We can do it however if we use social engineering on victim and then victim himself opens the port for us and then we can hack it.